# Показать координаты точки графика при наведении

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

есть график функции типа chart. Необходимо написать код, что бы по наведению мышки на точку графика, показывались координаты точки.

Реализация вывода графика :

```
int x = 0; 
for (double i = -Period; i <= Period; i += step) { 
    chart.Visible = true;
    chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline; 
    mas_MyGraphic5[x] = FuncForGraphic5(i); 
    chart5.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, FuncForGraphic5(i)); 
    x++;
}
```

Comment: что за _chart_? сами рисуете? компонент стандартный? компонент сторонний? веб? винформс? впф?

Comment: добавьте необходимый код и пояснения в сам вопрос

Comment: так что же такое _chart_? стандартный компонент? проект у вас WinForms?

Comment: Да стандартный, на сколько я знаю
используется для построения графиков функций и даиграм

Comment: @Kokoko строки `chart.Visible = true;` и `chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;` надо вынести за пределы цикла, т.е. поставить над `for`.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю установить следующее значение свойства `Series.ToolTip`:

```
chart.Series[0].ToolTip = "X = #VALX, Y = #VALY";
```

В этом случае никакого дополнительного кода писать не придется.

---

Еще можно подписаться на событие [`Chart.GetToolTipText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.gettooltiptext.aspx), и, используя передаваемый в обработчик экземпляр класса [`ToolTipEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.tooltipeventargs.aspx), вычислять и выводить в ToolTip что заблагорассудится.

```
chart.GetToolTipText += chart_GetToolTipText;
```

Обработчик:

```
private void chart_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    // Если текст в подсказке уже есть, то ничего не меняем.
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Text))
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType);

    switch (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType)
    {
        case ChartElementType.DataPoint:
        case ChartElementType.DataPointLabel:
        case ChartElementType.Gridlines:
        case ChartElementType.Axis:
        case ChartElementType.TickMarks:
        case ChartElementType.PlottingArea:
            // Первый ChartArea
            var area = chart.ChartAreas[0];

            // Его относительные координаты (в процентах от размеров Chart)
            var areaPosition = area.Position;

            // Переводим в абсолютные
            var areaRect = new RectangleF(areaPosition.X * chart.Width / 100, areaPosition.Y * chart.Height / 100,
                areaPosition.Width * chart.Width / 100, areaPosition.Height * chart.Height / 100);

            // Область построения (в процентах от размеров area)
            var innerPlot = area.InnerPlotPosition;

            double x = area.AxisX.Minimum +
                        (area.AxisX.Maximum - area.AxisX.Minimum) * (e.X - areaRect.Left - innerPlot.X * areaRect.Width / 100) /
                        (innerPlot.Width * areaRect.Width / 100);
            double y = area.AxisY.Maximum -
                        (area.AxisY.Maximum - area.AxisY.Minimum) * (e.Y - areaRect.Top - innerPlot.Y * areaRect.Height / 100) /
                        (innerPlot.Height * areaRect.Height / 100);

            Console.WriteLine("{0:F2} {1:F2}", x, y);
            e.Text = String.Format("{0:F2} {1:F2}", x, y);
            break;
    }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что координаты вычисляются верно и засылаются в `e.Text`, лично у меня ToolTip отображается далеко не всегда. Поэтому для верности я печатаю их в консоль. А вы вместо этого можете их отображать в каком-нибудь контроле.

Comment: а как реализовать вывод координат при наведении курсора на график?

Comment: @Kokoko Никак. В этом нет необходимости, они будут показаны во всплывающей подсказке.

Comment: всплывающая подсказка всплывает только когда наводишь на сам график, мне бы хотелось такого же результата, при наведении курсора на любую точку

Comment: @Kokoko, а если в точке нет графика. что должно вывестись?

Comment: координаты данной точки

Comment: @Kokoko Добавил второй вариант. Он уже потребует от вас кода - вам предлагается по мышиным координатам сформировать отображаемый текст.

Comment: @DmitryD. будет замечательно, если напишете пример обработчика этого события

Comment: @Kokoko Добавил пример.